# Unexpected behavior when validating a session token using parse.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I'm trying to build a simple application with parse.com as my user manager.

I would like to make a login call to parse.com from my client side, and call my node.js server with the user's session token (I'll add it as a cookie). In the server side, I'll validate the session (using https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-validating) and allow access only if the session is valid.

For example (in my server):

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res, next) {
     var token = getTokenFromRequest(req);
     if(tokenIsValid(token)) {
         next();
     } else { // Redirect... } 
});

app.get('/api/doSomething', function(req, res) {
  // Do something....
});
```

- the tokenIsValid(token) function should be implemented using https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-validating.

However, it seems that the REST API user validation returns the user **even if the user is logged out** (expected to return 'invalid session').
Is this a bug in the REST API user validation? What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way for doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see your request

Comment: I'm trying to understand why the REST call to https://api.parse.com/1/users/me returns the user object event if the user is logged out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via REST there's no concept of **sessions** really. REST calls are meant to be stateless meaning that the (current) user at `/me` will be serialized from the token provided. If the token is associated to a user it will return the JSON representation of that user otherwise in returns an error.
One way or another that call is asynchronous so you can't really use it in and if statement.

You can do:

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res, next) {
     var token = getTokenFromRequest(req);
     serializeUserFromToken(token,function(err,parseResponse) {
        if(err) return next(err)
        if(parseResponse.code && parseResponse.code === 101){
            // called to parse succedded but the token is not valid
            return next(parseResponse);
        }
        // parseResponse is the current User.
        next();
     }); 
});
```

Where `serializeUserFromToken` makes a request to **Parse** with the token in the `X-Parse-Session-Token` header field.

Comment: I agree! however, the serializeUserFromToken returns the serialized user event if the user is logged out. I thought that it checks first if the session is logged in or something...

Comment: You need to clear the cookie and the token from the session when you logout the current user. The call to Parse should have nothing to do with how you handle the session.

Comment: The Parse JS SDK stores the sessions in the front-end in localStorage and that is independent of your backend service. Instead of logging in the user in the front-end and THEN in the back-end you should log them in the backend and then via the `become` method of the JS SDK log them in in the front-end. It seems that you are handling logins separately in the back and front end respectively. Take a look at this: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-become_anchor

Comment: I think I got what you are saying... I'm just new to this flow...
Thanks so much!